# Strange unicode characters when centering a minipage

Tags: minipage

I need a somewhat centered box to emphasize a quote. I dont know where I found it, but my current approach is the following:

```
\begin{center}
​\begin{minipage}{0.9\textwidth}
How can we build computer systems that automatically improve with experience, and what are the fundamental laws that govern all learning processes?
\end{minipage}
\end{center}
```

This yields the expected result, but I have a problem with some weird unicode characters appearing to the left of the box:

[image]

Does anyone have an idea what causes this behavior?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Your snippet is absolutely fine. Please give us an minimal working example which is compilable and results in this error. Like this, we have not idea where the symbols came from.

Comment: There is an [invisible char](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200B/index.htm), use an editor showing you those properly. Right now, delete from the ending of `How` to the beginning of the line (press `home`).

Comment: How about using the `quote` environment instead? You don't need to go through all the trouble.

Comment: @Johannes_B Yes, it's U+200B and, probably, t-h- is using `latin1` as option to `inputenc` (or no `inputenc` at all). Using `quote` is surely better.

Comment: Package `csquotes` provides you with even more powerful commands to typeset quotes of any kind.

Comment: thanks guys!! sorry for not providing the MWE. my preamble is just so packed I didnt even know which parts of it to be relevant -.-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an invisible char in your text. Place your cursor in front of `\begin{minipage}` and you will notice that you can do one backspace without any visible effect. That was the one... The problem does not appear without `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`. That's why we always need a complete minimal working example (just for the next time).

Here is your approach and the nicer one with `csquotes`:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\begin{document}
\blindtext
\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{0.9\textwidth}
How can we build computer systems that automatically improve with experience, and what are the fundamental laws that govern all learning processes?
\end{minipage}
\end{center}
\blindtext
\blockquote{How can we build computer systems that automatically improve with experience, and what are the fundamental laws that govern all learning processes?

%%% empty line needet in order to force this to get set in display mode. Or you reduce the `parthreshold` option of csquotes
}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]